# Remove different links from MySQL table

Tags: mysql

How i could remove different links i have in a MySQL field in many rows? I couldn't find a query for that.

I don't have much experience with MySQL, the ideal solutions would be something that begins with something and ends with something.

Example:
On table 'ads' i have a field called 'description' that has the ad description text. I have links inside the descriptions and i want to remove them all, but those links have different urls from ads to ads. I don't want to delete the text of the link, just the link itself `<a class="something" href="http://someurl.com">Link text</a>`

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question again, please see if it's ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a better explanation of your problem and a sample of code.
Although, if i'm right on what you want to achieve, you might need something like this below.

**Example:**

```
UPDATE ads SET description=REPLACE(description,'whatYouWantToDelete','')
```

The above will remove everything in your column that contains the string foo.

**UPDATE:**

These might be helpful.

[Remove HTML tags from record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record)

[Removing links from posts in wordpress using query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356897/removing-links-from-posts-in-wordpress-using-query)

Comment: Hi @Makis, i just add some more information on my question, please see if you understand it.

Comment: I thing this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030143/sql-statement-to-remove-part-of-a-string

Comment: No because the rest of the html tag is not removed. Also the replace souldn't work because the urls are different i am correct?

Comment: Yes the replace should not work, that was my answer before you edited your post. I'm searching for it, i hope i can help you!

Comment: Check those please.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356897/removing-links-from-posts-in-wordpress-using-query